# How to get two projects to reference the same 3rd party assembly, and have their types be equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vsto, .net-assembly

I have my main project, and another project for unit tests. Both reference the same 3rd party assembly (in my case its `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`)

If I compare the `Type` of an object created in my unit test project to one that was created by the main project's code, they aren't equal.

Here is some simplified code from my test

```
// Comes from my main project's .DLL
var foreignProjectObj = new ForeignObject();
// Some object created by ForeignObject, defined in the 3rd party assembly.
var foreignCreatedMailItem = foreignProjectObj.MailItem;
var foreignMailItemType = typeof(foreignCreatedMailItem);

// Referencing the 3rd party assembly from the Unit Test project
var localMailItem = new MailItem();
var localType = typeof(localMailItem);

Debug.WriteLine(localType.Equals(foreignMailItemType)); // False.
```

I can see these two types are in fact different by looking at their  `Assembly` properties:

MailItem created inside ForeignObject:
`Assembly = {MyOutlookAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adc2a93327de863b}`

MailItem created from the Unit Test project:
`Assembly = {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c}`

My question is how do I get both projects to create objects that have equal `Type` information. Both projects reference the same .DLL, but the objects instantiated by my main project are still of a different type than those created in my unit test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are embedding the interop types into your MyOutlookAddIn assembly. In the MyOutlookAddIn project, expand the References node. Find the Outlook reference, right-click on it and select Properties. Change the `Embed Interop Types` property to `False`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally? I think I do need to Embed Interop Types when I do a real build, just not for Unit Tests.

Comment: You probably don't need to Embed Interop Types. I write 2 or 3 of this type of application a month and have written literally dozens of them over the past 15 years. I've never needed to embed the interop types.

Comment: You're right! I had some trivial compiler errors to fix, but this did the trick. I owe you a beer.